# Replacing string path of object via replace() and regex causing errors

Tags: javascript, regex, image, path

I am trying t make a game in which a player holds a weapon, but the type of weapon can change. I am trying to set a "material", or characteristic, of each weapon, which should change the path of the image, so the correct image is drawn to the screen. However, it does not seem to work. Here is my current code:

```
let magnet_image = new Image();
magnet_image.src = "assets/images/weapons/magnet.png";

magnet = new Weapon(magnet_image);

class Weapon {

    image_path;

    constructor (image_path) {

        image_path.src.replace(/magnet/gi, "magnet_black");
        console.log(image_path)

        this.x = player.x + player.width / 2;
        this.y = player.y + player.height / 2;
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
        this.angle = 0;
        this.material = "";
        this.image = image_path;
        this.distance = 50;

    }

}
```

I am trying to switch from `"assets/images/weapons/magnet.png"` to `"assets/images/weapons/magnet_black.png"`, but the console.log statement returns `"assets/images/weapons/magnet.png"` (AKA the incorrect path). Even the default magnet image is drawn on the screen, not the black magnet. How can I fix this?

Comment: it's working, replace it's i think the name in js is _pure_, anyways it doesn't alter the input, try `console.log(image_path.src.replace(/magnet/gi, "magnet_black"));`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi I just tried that, doing so gives me two outputs. First is the correct image path, and then an output of "undefined". Here: console.log(magnet_image.src.replace(/magnet/gi, "magnet_black"));
VM256:1 http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/images/weapons/magnet_black.png
undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const regex = /magnet/gi
let newWord = magnet.replace(regex, 'magnet_black')
console.log(newWord)
```

```js
let magnet = 'assets/images/weapons/magnet.png'
const regex = /magnet/gi

magnet.replace(regex, 'magnet_black')
console.log(magnet)

magnet = magnet.replace(regex, 'magnet_black')
console.log(magnet)
```

Oh lol I think I've figured it out. You've not assigned the replaced string to image_path.src

Comment: I tried doing "image_path = image_path.src.replace("magnet", "magnet_black");", but this error returns: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or VideoFrame)'

Comment: Try typing in image_path.src = image_path.src.replace(/magnet/gi, "magnet_black")

Comment: If you've typed in what you did above, then you're replacing the Image() object with a string instead of replacing the image.src (which is a string value). That would be the cause of the error